# Incorrect output from the voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, stm32, linear-regulator

[image]

Hello,

I have a circuit that I designed myself. In summary, I feed the circuit with 2 CR2032 type batteries and try to get 3.3 V output from the LD1117 type regulator. However, **I get 4.7 V output from the regulator**. I also observe a **drop in battery voltage**, interestingly when I feed it on battery.
By voltage drop, I mean it happens instantaneously, maybe it would be more correct to specify it as **voltage loss**.

Let me share with you the situations I have examined.

There was no change of state when I first connected parallel capacitors to the circuit. **edit: I mean 10uf and 100nF(capacitors on the datasheet)**

I tested the battery packs and batteries also out of circuit. There is no problem with them either.

When I set the same regulator up to the bluepill supply in the breadbord and tried to supply it without capacitor, I got a constant 3.3V output. However, when I supply the circuit with DC supply 6V from the outside, I constantly get 4.7V from the regulator output. And when I feed it with the battery, it initially comes to 4.7 in the same way, then the voltage of the batteries starts to decrease in a short time. When I deactivate, their voltage comes back to 3V.

I haven't had the opportunity to test it yet, but I'm thinking about the question of whether reverse current is coming from somewhere. Do you think **putting a diode on the regulator output** can solve it? I am open to your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: The [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LD1117V33.pdf) Figure 4 shows 100 nF on the input and 10 uF on the output. Your schematic doesn't. Did you feel that they were optional? ;^)

Comment: As I said "There was no change of state when I first connected parallel capacitors to the circuit." I also tried adding capacitors to the circuit, but it did not change :/

Comment: OK. Just checking all the silly stuff. The pinout is 1, 2, 3: GND, Vout, Vin. Nothing mixed up there?

Comment: Give it some dummy load with a resistor.

Comment: @winny, I thought of that but the datasheet Table 9 says that regulation is 10 mV max for Io = 0 to 800 mA so it shouldn't need a load and the OP is running on batteries so s/he won't want one. It might be worth a try though.

Comment: @Transistor 1117 not needing a minimum load all off the sudden? 

Comment: This sounds like mixed up wiring, maybe a missing ground connection to the regulator.  Worryingly you also seem to show another load connected *through* the MCU rather than in parallel with it.  Beware that even if working as intended this idea is likely to drain your coin cells fairly quickly.

Comment: [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LD1117V33.pdf), As in Figure 2, the pinouts were checked over and over again. @Transistor,
When I connect ~100 ohm into Vin, I get to almost 3.2 V but again battery voltage drop is a problem, also I see 64 mA on the current display of the Voltage Source when it feeds the circuit.

Comment: I've to say also, both pinouts on MCU are 3.3V voltage outputs.[Bluepill Pinouts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcomponents101.com%2Fmicrocontrollers%2Fstm32f103c8t8-blue-pill-development-board&psig=AOvVaw0eDS94g4154fAdcQzSe6OP&ust=1600549440069000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKiO7LjN8-sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ)

Comment: By "connect ~100 ohm into Vin" I presume you mean you connect it in series between the 6 V source and the regulator input. With a 6 V supply and a 100 ohm load the max current you could get would be 60 mA. It sounds as though you have connected a 100 ohm resistor across the 6 V battery. How about a good sharp, well cropped photo of your setup?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I made the resistor addition I mentioned externally just to test it. There is no such resistance in the current setup. But do you think it makes sense to add resistance where Vin is in order to pull the Voltage where I want it? In addition, how would you suggest that I test a possible Reverse current incoming situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has been solved as of yesterday. I noticed a voltage of about 30mV in the ground of my circuit board. For the same reason the regulator seems to be raising the voltage above 3.3 by taking the ref voltage. I think this is caused by the ground touch of one of the solders I made on the circuit. Because I did not have a problem with my other pcbs with the same feature. Thank you